# CSS causes the canvas games buttons and on screen clicks to break. How do I fix it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

Why centering and even adding a header tag is causing the code's buttons to go off of the input area? I want to add some designs to the background but have no idea why the buttons are off of the input area. It is for a canvas game called bug smasher that needs mouse input.

Javascript:

```
// Create the canvas
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var timer = 0;
var caught = false;
var fps = 10;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
canvas.width = 800;
canvas.height = 544;

// Background image
var bgReady = false;
var bgImage = new Image();

bgImage.onload = function () {
    bgReady = true;
};
bgImage.src = "images/background.png";

// bug image
var bugReady = false;
var bugImage = new Image();
bugImage.onload = function () {
    bugReady = true;
};
bugImage.src = "images/bug.png";

var bug = {};
var bugCaught = 0;
// When bug is caught, reset
var reset = function () {
    bug.x = 40 + (Math.random() * (canvas.width - 70));
    do {
        bug.y = 40 + (Math.random() * (canvas.height - 70));
    }
    while (bug.y < 100)
};

//mousedown event
window.addEventListener("mousedown", onMouseDown, false);
function onMouseDown(e) {

    if (e.button != 0) return;

    mouseXinCanvas = e.clientX;
    mouseYinCanvas = e.clientY;

    if (bugBody(bug, mouseXinCanvas, mouseYinCanvas)) {
        caught = true;
        clearInterval(timer);
        timer = setInterval(reset, 20000 / fps);
        reset();
    }
    if (ResetScore(mouseXinCanvas, mouseYinCanvas)) {
        location.reload();
    }
    if (ResetSpeed(mouseXinCanvas, mouseYinCanvas)) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        timer = setInterval(reset, 20000 / fps);
        reset();
        render();
    }
};

//bug's body define
function bugBody(bug, x, y) {

    if (x <= (bug.x + 80)
        && bug.x <= (x + 80)
        && y <= (bug.y + 80)
        && bug.y <= (y + 80)
    ) {
        fps = fps + 5;
        bugCaught++;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
};

//Reset Score box
function ResetScore(x, y) {

    if (x > (305)
        && x < (545)
        && y > (15)
        && y < (85)
    ) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
};

//Reset speed box
function ResetSpeed(x, y) {
    if (x > (605)
        && x < (845)
        && y > (15)
        && y < (85)
    ) {
        fps = 10;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
};

// Draw everything
var render = function () {

   //===========================================================
   // add the following line to clear the display.

   ctx.clearRect(0,0,ctx.canvas.width,ctx.canvas.height);


    if (bgReady) {
        ctx.drawImage(bgImage, 0, 100);
    }
    if (bugReady) {
        ctx.drawImage(bugImage, bug.x, bug.y);
    }
    if (caught == true) {
        if (bgReady) {
            ctx.drawImage(bgImage, 0, 100);
        }
        caught = false;
    }

    // Score, Title
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(65, 226, 24)";
    ctx.font = "34px Helvetica";
    ctx.textAlign = "left";
    ctx.textBaseline = "top";
    ctx.fillText("Bug Smasher", 5, 40);
    ctx.font = "20px Helvetica";
    ctx.fillText("Score: " + bugCaught, 10, 10);



    // Reset Score, Speed button
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(30, 168, 99)";
    ctx.fillRect(250, 10, 250, 80);
    ctx.fillRect(520, 10, 250, 80);
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(30, 168, 99)";
    ctx.fillRect(255, 15, 240, 70);
    ctx.fillRect(525, 15, 240, 70);
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255, 255, 255)";
    ctx.font = "34px Arial";
    ctx.fillText("Reset Score", 275, 30);
    ctx.fillText("Reset Speed", 545, 30);

};

// The main game loop
var main = function () {
    render();
    // Request to do this again ASAP
    requestAnimationFrame(main);
};

// Cross-browser support for requestAnimationFrame
var w = window;
requestAnimationFrame = w.requestAnimationFrame || w.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || w.msRequestAnimationFrame || w.mozRequestAnimationFrame;
// Let's play this game!
//var then = Date.now();
reset();
main();
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content = "width=device-width, initial-scale = 1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Assignment5.css">   
        <title>Assignment 5</title>
        
    </head>
    <body>
      <main>
     <script src="Assignment5.js"></script>
     </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add other elements to your code your `<canvas>` element will shift accordingly. What you are not accounting for in your mouse function is the canvas position in relation to the window.

I'm sure you've noticed that when you add elements the canvas moves down but the collision for the button and the bug do not move in relation to the canvas. So in your mouse function you need to subtract the canvas x and y position

```
window.addEventListener("mousedown", onMouseDown, false);
function onMouseDown(e) {

    let canvasBounds = canvas.getBoundingClientRect(); //add this

    if (e.button != 0) return;

    mouseXinCanvas = e.clientX - canvasBounds.x; //can also be canvasBounds.left
    mouseYinCanvas = e.clientY - canvasBounds.y; //can also be canvasBoudns.top

    if (bugBody(bug, mouseXinCanvas, mouseYinCanvas)) {...
```